# Processing of positions (pairs) to get indexes

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

Imagine we have a list:

```
in = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {4, 4}, {5, 2}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}}
```

Needed (general approach for matrixes like 100 x 100):

```
out = {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 5}, {6}}
```

Explanation: there are positions of elements in a square matrix (in lower triangle).
I need to group rows indexes such that elements that interact with other indexes should group with those indexes in sublists. Note for example that `6` is not in any other position except {6, 6} and so it stays alone.

What for? Just a step in q-analysis as of vintage Atkin(1972). 
Stuck a bit to get a nice solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you are looking for connected components of a graph:

```
ConnectedComponents[Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ in]]
```

> {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 5}, {6}}

Comment: this also works `WeaklyConnectedComponents[Graph[Rule @@@ in]]`